# How to delete or change drupal 7 module release?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, auto-update

I have real problem. I have made a release of new drupal module on drupal.org (version 2.9) with errors. And i need to fix it. But i don't know how.

Lately i released 3.0 version with the fix in a new branch 7.x-3.x with tag 7.x-3.0 but autoupdate in drupal dashboard shows only 2.9 version.

So the questions is:
Do the versions above 2.9 for modules are valid in drupal.org?
How can i rollback the version number or delete it?

Thanks to everyone who will answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **[you can't](https://www.drupal.org/node/128614)**.  You can [submit a request to a webmaster to take the 3.0 release down](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters) if you like, but there is no guarantee that they will take it down.

There is a very deliberate scheme for module release numbers.

7.x-**2.9** - The **2** is the major release, and the **9** is the incremental or patch version.

You might think that 3.0 comes after 2.9, but it doesn't (unless it's a major release).  **2.10 comes after 2.9, not 3.0**.

The first number before the decimal represents a "feature set" and this is what is meant by major release.  [This is explained in great detail here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/choosing-a-drupal-version/what-do-version-numbers-mean-on-contributed-modules-and-themes).